# Updating regions in RegionBootstrap

Tags: android, altbeacon

I have an application that is using RegionBootstrap to look for a set of regions.  In the onCreate method of my Application class I instantiate the RegionBootstrap and pass it a list of Regions.  This works great, and as expected.  Is there a way to update the regions that the RegionBootstrap is looking for later on, after instantiation?  I have a database table that is storing some region data, and that can get updated throughout the lifetime of the application.  I have a content observer watching for updates but I don't know how to add/remove regions accordingly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the late reply to this question.  I think you can find an answer to a similar question here:

[How can I "refresh" my RegionBootstrap (Android Beacon Library)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097586/how-can-i-refresh-my-regionbootstrap-android-beacon-library)

Quote:

You should construct a RegionBootstrap only once.  If you want to alter the monitored regions by adding new ones, just do so directly on BeaconManager like this:

```
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It was a very short two line answer :)  Nevertheless,  I have copied the two lines verbatim.